# stability and energy gap

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

We know that the lower the energy gap between bonding and antibonding orbital the easier it is to break the bond making it unstable. However, in a conjugated double bond, the overlapping of wavefunctions cause the energy gap between the bonding and antibonding orbital go down. Then why conjugated double bonded molecules are more stable??